# Import XML into mySQL with identical attribute name for several node levels

Tags: mysql, xml

I try to import a XML file into a MYSQL table using the LOAD XML function:

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'test.xml INTO TABLE edge_delete ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<edge>';
```

the XML File is structured like this:

```
    <netstate xmlns:xsi=....>
<timestep time="2">
    <edge id="10">
        <lane id="10_0">
            <vehicle id="veh1" pos="4.60" speed="0.00"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
</timestep>
```

The Problem: 
All node levels start with the attribute "id". The import does not distinguish between the node levels.
Each node level should be one corresponding column in my sql table: edge | lane | vehicle id |...

Thank you for you help

Comment: MySQL's LOAD XML function can't handle all kinds of XML formats.. think your better off programming a XML parser within a programming language.. You also might want to try loading the xml with load_file()  ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file ) function and parse the XML yourself with ExtractValue()  ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html )

Answer (score 0):

A solution which worked for me:
Use a python script which replaces the "id" attributes with another attribute string (e.g. with "edge"). The script replaces the string. Maybe not the best and efficient way, but solves the problem.
Now I can import all columns of the XML file into the mySQL table.

Another workaround: Using a text editor with a find/replace function.
Did not work properly with the tools I found for large xml files > 1GB.

The script can be found here:

https://studiofreya.com/2016/11/17/replace-string-in-xml-file-with-python/#comment-86628